# How to send a message from java restful server to gcm server

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, google-cloud-messaging

I have a java restful webservice (1) and an Android application that consumes this (2). A third application is responsible for entering data into the database via the webservice. I want that when the third application enter new data in my db, the webservice notifies the  android application by GCM. My Android application is able to receive the reg-Id GCM. (I have the project created in google developers etc, server api key..)

I tried this: when the third app accesses the URI to enter data byPOST, sending the message to the google servers. DOES NOT WORK

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(Usuarios entity) {
 String deviceId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...;

Sender sender = new Sender("AIzaSyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
 Message message = new Message.Builder()
.addData("message", "this is the message")
.addData("other-parameter", "some value")
.build();

  Result result = sender.send(message, deviceId, 3);

    super.create(entity);
}
```

I have also tried to create a servlet. But does not work

```
@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet_1", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet_1"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {    
    processRequest(request, response);
}
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   Sender sender = new Sender("AIzaSyBNFur3sFJpMujkVYW9rzEq3udI0khRCOI");
 Message message = new Message.Builder()
.addData("message", "this is the message")
.addData("other-parameter", "some value")
.build();
  Result result = sender.send(message, "xxxxxxxxxxxx", 3);

    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

}

Some idea ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you have solved the problem. but it amy be helpful to others so i am posting the answer.

choose any rest client(jersey rest client) or normal http URL post.

post the request to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send url

set two variable to http header

Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY
Content-Type: application/json

payload json should be as below.

```
 {
      "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx..."],
      "data" : {
        ///your data goes here 
      },
    }
```

example

```
  { "data": {
        "score": "5x1",
        "time": "15:10"
      },
      "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
    }
```

note - registration_ids are device registration ids.

now post to the rest.

for more information please check [this](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html).

**Sample code**

package com.ajs.ajstest.gcmpost;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

/**
 *
 * @author nirmal
 */
public class GCMPost {

```
public static void main(String ar[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String json="{ \"data\": {" +
                "    \"score\": \"5x1\"," +
                "    \"time\": \"15:10\"" +
                "  }," +
                "  \"registration_ids\": [\"4\", \"8\", \"15\", \"16\", \"23\", \"42\"]" +
                "}";
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
httpost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpost.setHeader("Authorization","YOUR_API_KEY");

httpost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
}
```

}

maven dependancies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.6</version>
  <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>
```